# Find the PDF of $P\{X\geq x\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I encountered this new problem that states $P\{X\geq x\} = 1$ when $x\leq x_0$ and $P\{X\geq x\} = \left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right) ^ \alpha$ if $x>x_0$. Let $x_0>0$ and $\alpha>0$ and be constants.

Well, because $F(x) = P\{X\geq x\}$, I can just differentiate this CDF to find the PDF: $F^\prime(x) =f(x)$. Which yields $f(x\leq x_0) = 0$ and $f(x>x_0)=\frac{-\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$.

Is this correct? Also is the domain weird because the $P\{X\geq x\}$ instead of $P\{X\leq x\}$?

Comment: $F(x)=1-\mathsf P\{X\gt x\}$, so $f(x)=-\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P\{X\gt x\}}{\mathrm d x}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp which is $f(x>x_0)=\frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$. But is this PDF valid for $P\{X\geq x\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note: the probability density function is the derivative of the cummulative distribution function.  You have a survival function, which is related as such:

$$\begin{align}F(x)&=1-\mathsf P(X\geqslant x)\\[2ex]f(x)&=-\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(X\geqslant x)}{\mathrm d x}\end{align}$$

So with $$\mathsf P(X\geq x)=\begin{cases} 1&:& x\leq x_0\\ (x_0/x)^\alpha&:& x>x_0\end{cases}$$

Therefore the probability density function is :

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&:&x\leq x_0\\\alpha\,{x_0}^\alpha /x^{1+\alpha}&:&x> x_0\end{cases}$$

Which is a valid probability density function when $x_0>0$ and $\alpha>0$.

- $\forall x~.f(x)\geqslant 0$
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\mathrm d x=1$